# Possible to get IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2 to "port-forward" port 80 for certain domains to other ports?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, subdomain, port-forwarding

I have IIS set up on my server, but also Apache x2 (other products which comes with their own servers, cannot be integrated into IIS.)

Is it possible for me to "port-forward" certain domains on port 80 (that IIS handles) to those other ports?

For instance:

- www.vkarlsen.no -> IIS
- svn.vkarlsen.no -> port 81 on same machine
- teamcity.vkarlsen.no -> port 82 on same machine

Or do I just need to set up those domains and redirect to the correct port? I'd like the domain name and url to be transparent to the user, but perhaps that won't work.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're mixed two possible solutions:
1) If you want to access various services with different port numbers (svn.vkarlsen.no:81, teamcity.vkarlsen.no:82) - just create multiply sites in your IIS and specify unique port number for every site.
2) If you want to setup all your sites to share one IP - check IIS configuration for "host headers" option.

Comment: I want the third option than you didn't mention. I want to reach the server hosted on port 82 (internally) by going through port 80 on IIS. Basically, I would like http://svn.vkarlsen.no/svn/project/trunk to transparently be remapped to http://svn.vkarlsen.no:81/svn/trunk/trunk, without the user having to know this. If I can't do this, I'll just leave the ports as is. They work, I was just looking for something esthetically pleasing :)

Comment: Argh, Ok. 
Seems you need HTTP redirect or URL rewrite.

Comment: HTTP Redirect doesn't seem to be working properly with Subversion, and I didn't really expect it to either. I guess I'll just leave it as it is, with the two other ports.

Answer (score 1):

This post describes how to complete the task if you have IIS 7.5:

http://jonalb.com/post/2010/10/23/TeamCity-On-Port-80-In-IIS.aspx

I'm trying this out now.